# Docker-compose file build context explanation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker-compose file that is working but I have poor understanding of the file

In the following file how can I interpret
build:
context:
ulimits:
sysctl:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  zabbix-server:
    container_name: zabbix-server
    build:
      context: zabbix-server-mysql   
    image: zabbix:ubuntu-5.4.4-custom    
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 20000
        hard: 40000
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65000
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects=0
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[build and context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build)

[ulimits 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ulimit-soft-limits-and-hard-limits-in-linux/) [ulimits 2](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/)

[sysctl 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) [sysctl 2](https://linuxize.com/post/sysctl-command-in-linux/)

and many many other articles